# subCategories function is defiened but all what I get is Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::subCategories()"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have category table which has parent_category_id column since each category can have more than sub category so I in my Category model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    //
    public function subCategories(){
        $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_category_id');
    }
    public function products(){
        $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
    public function parentCategory(){
        $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_category_id');
    }
```

but when I try 
`Category::where('parent_category_id', null)->where('is_hidden', 0)->subCategories()->get()`

all I get 
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::subCategories()"`

how to solve this?

Comment: Add return to your functions. Like: `return  $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_category_id');`

Comment: @mare96 I have added the return but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$categories = Category::with('subCategories')->where('parent_category_id', null)
          ->where('is_hidden', 0)->get();
```

And if you want to access to subCategories you can do like this:

```
$subCategories = $categories->subCategories();
```

Comment: please explain for me why your way works but not mine? if you may please because I am trying to understand

Comment: If works, mark it as answer and vote up. You can read about relations on this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) . Good luck!